# How to focus button in CSS class by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I have problem, how to focus to CSS style by Jquery and JavaScript. I have this code:

```
   it('Add new group', () => {
        cy.waitForInitLoad();
        cy.get('#dxToolbarMenu').then(($el) => {
            
            expect($el[0].className).to.equal(
              'dx-item dx-menu-item dx-menu-item-has-text dx-menu-item-has-icon',
            )
          })
```

Original CSS from web is in this picture:

[image: CSS from web page]

Comment: First of all you shouldn't compare the className to a given string, as the order of the classes has no logic and may change. (Plus it would break your test if one class is ever added to this div)

Comment: I also recomend using id's. Reason is a better search performance and not so long search strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('#dxToolbarMenu')
  .find('.dx-item.dx-menu-item.dx-menu-item-has-text.dx-menu-item-has-icon')
```

You can also add `focus()` to focus on the Element.

```js
cy.get('#dxToolbarMenu')
  .find('.dx-item.dx-menu-item.dx-menu-item-has-text.dx-menu-item-has-icon')
  .first() //In case of multiple elements with the same selector consider take the first one
  .focus()
```